# How to create a bean which extends JpaRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to write a unit test for a DAO. But in our project, we have more than 200 DAO and 200 model classes. And we use jpaRepository to write DAO. But I have a problem when I run my unit test. I take a lot of time to create application context. I have an idea. I only create a bean DAO which I want to test instead of creating all DAO. But DAO of jpa:repository is interface, so I can not create a bean with class is interface. If creating a bean which extend jpa:reponsitories is imposible, can you suggest me other ways to run unit faster.
my unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/spring/testContext.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
// Importance, as the transaction will be rollback for each test
// give us a clean state.
@Transactional
public class CommunicationDetailDAOTest
{
    @Autowired
    CommunicationDetailDAO communicationDetailDAO;

    @Test
    public void testSomeThing()
    {

        System.out.println("helloworld");
    }
}
```

file testContext.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:META-INF/spring/properties/prism_local_persistence_test.properties"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mobilePersistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <!--using postgres driver-->
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManager"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring Data Jpa setup -->
    <jpa:repositories
            base-package="com.discorp.model.dao"
            entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManager"
            transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"></jpa:repositories>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.qsoft"/>-->
</beans>
```

and file persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="mobilePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.discorp.model.common.Address</class>
        <class>com.discorp.model.common.Application</class>
        .... more than 200 model classes
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate." value="false"/>            -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make different config files for different tests an include only the dao(s) needed by the test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
...
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
...
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
...">

...

<jpa:repositories base-package="path.to.your" >
    <repository:include-filter type="assignable" expression="path.to.your.Repository"/>
</jpa:repositories>
```

Comment: When I configure like: 
`<jpa:repositories
            base-package="com.discorp.model.dao"
            entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManager"
            transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager">

            <repository:include-filter type="communicationDetailDAO" expression="com.discorp.model.dao.CommunicationDetailDAO"/>

    </jpa:repositories>`, I have an error The prefix "repository" for element "repository:include-filter" is not bound

Comment: You have to add `xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd` to your `<beans>`-tag.